# Space simulation in the world gives rotation error which is not in the local, the main part that i need to use the world space

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system

[Local space simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkaKX.png)

[World Space simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHvKZ.png)

Comment: Hello Razy, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please have a read over the "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" guide so that your question format is in-line with the guidelines and others can help you; thanks!

Comment: I did everything right, what's the problem?